# How to paginate data using NSIndexPath (CoreData)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, core-data

I have a table view controller which list the contents of an entity in Core Data, after cell click it fetches the details of that particular entity using NSIndexPath and and push data to another view controller for detailed summary, in that view controller I want to paginate all the contents of that entity so that it is not hassle for the user to go back and select another data from the table. What is the best solution for this? Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to pass the array of items that the table is using for a datasource to the new view controller, along with the index of the selected item. When the user hits next or previous, they'll be able to traverse the array by just increasing or decreasing the current index of the item being viewed and refreshing the view with the new object's data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm just wondering if this approach is ok given that I have large amount of data?

Comment: Well if you're concerned about having a large dataset, you don't need to necessarily store all data for every object in the array. The array that you pass could just be a an array of ID's in the same order as they are shown in the table view, and when the user changes pages, it can grab the information for the new item to be displayed by querying for the entity with an ID matching the ID stored at the new index.

Comment: Anytime! If this answer has helped you please vote on it and mark it as accepted. Thanks and good luck!